# How can I extend my wifi to get 50 more meters of range?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-transfer

I'm using [Linksys WAG120N](http://www.linksys.com/en-mea/products/gateways/WAG120N) Wireless-N Home ADSL2+ Modem Router.

My router's WIFI is not that powerful. My other rooms don't get a good signal because of  where the Router is located. Would a repeater do the job?

I want to be able to use my laptop, or cellphone around 50 meters away and still get a good signal.

Comment: Some countries allow much bigger output power then 100 mW. Connect via terminal to your router, changer country setting and increase your power to 200 mW or so. Now you know what to look for and google will bring you forward.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't hurt to give a little look at the *WiFi range extenders / bridge* section of [NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Wireless-Range-Extender-Media-Bridge/SubCategory/ID-2948?Tid=17195) (I'm from France but it's a big player out there).

The main issue you're going to run into will be the *bridge* system but if you're a little tech savvy it should be a mere nuisance.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 3):

The following 2 articles have good tips to boost WIFI

- http://lifehacker.com/5931743/top-10-ways-to-boost-your-home-wi+fi
- http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2372811,00.asp

You can try some of the Tips like

- Relocating your Router to a better location can help. even if you add a repeter it should also get the signal to send it further
- Choose the right wireless channel(http://lifehacker.com/5831845/know-your-network-lesson-3-maximizing-yours-speed-performance-and-wireless-signal)
- Get Rid of Interference from Other Appliances
- Use parabolic reflector made from tin to increase range of signal (http://lifehacker.com/5839243/use-an-aluminum-can-as-a-wi+fi-extender)
- Upgrade firmware of your router

linksys you Router vendor also provides range expander
 - http://www.linksys.com/en-mea/products/rangeexpanders

Comment: Hmm got a Solution, I bought the Linksys from here before 2 Hours and going to Try with DD firmware update method let me playaround it and ill give the result :) http://www.ebay.in/itm/LINKSYS-WIFI-ROUTER-MODEL-WRT54G-/261406987430?ssPageName=ADME:L:OC:IN:3160